# why does the torque speed control panel of gazebo GUI disappear?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

when I updated the drcsim, now the torque speed position control panel of gazebo GUI  disappear, how to display it?
thank you
best
gd

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1880/why-does-the-torque-speed-control-panel-of-gazebo-gui--disappear?/) by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2013-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It's just hidden by default - just clock and drag the right side of the Gazebo window (there's a small "grip", three horizontal white lines) and you'll get the window.

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) with karma: 508 on 2013-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on 2013-03-16**:
I get it, thank you very much!